# Getting addresses from outlook using VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am trying to get the address associated with a user from Outlook using this following code and it seems to consistently fail on some machines:-

```
  var application = CurrentAppointmentItem.Application;
            var session = application.Session;
            var organizer = CurrentAppointmentItem.GetOrganizer();
            var recipient = session.CreateRecipient(organizer.Name);
            var addressEntry = recipient.AddressEntry;
            var propertyAccessor = addressEntry.PropertyAccessor;
            var addressProperty = propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101E");
```

The error is:-

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): The operation failed.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyAccessorClass.GetProperty(String SchemaName)
```

To be specific I am trying to get the SIP address (not the SMTP address) of the current user, does anyone have any ideas?

Extra info: despite the error message being on propertAccessor.GetProperty() it turns out that recipient.Resolve() fails for the recipient in the coded example.

Answer (score 0):

PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES is only available on the GAL address entries. It will not be present for one the one-off SMTP address entries.

What exactly and why are you truing to do?

Comment: I am trying to reliably get a SIP address of the organiser of the current appointment item.  Obviously the SMTP address can be fetched easily enough using recipient.Address but in this case I am after a SIP address.  The SIP address is visible in the Global Address book in the Email addresses tab and it this I need to be able to fetch.

Comment: Check the AddressEntry.Type property - if it s "SMTP", just use AddressEntry.Address. If it is "EX", use AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress. PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES may or may not be available.

Comment: Specifically I'm not after just the primary smtp address but all of the addresses associated with a recipient, any ideas on how to get them all including the alternative addresses?

Comment: PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES is all there is for Exchange users. For the one-off SMTP addresses, the regular AddressEntry.Address is all you have.

Comment: Sorry just realised I keep ignoring your point about the one-off SMTP address.  This isn't a one off address but a proper exchange user (or at least it should be).  It turns out the error message might actually be more of a symptom than a cause as upon investigation I have found  recipient.Resolve() is failing even though the recipient is the current user.  any idea why that might be?

Comment: If Resolve is failing, Recipient.AddressEntry will be null. Do you mean it resolves to a contact instead of a GAL entry?

Comment: Failing as in returning false.

Comment: Then how can you access Recipient.AddressEntry?

Comment: Good question, I looked at this again this morning and found that the above code actually works, the real only difference is that I'm searching on organizer.Address rather than organizer.Name.